# ReplaceWith carousel-inner with new items

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel, replacewith

Community :-)

this is my first Question. There are similar but I have a very special problem.
**I try to change the items of an bootstrap carousel on demand - but it frozes after that.** 
If I do, it shows the first active but I cannot use the slide buttons and indicators.
I the [Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/bp/h4udkJOXkr) I have triggered the replacement with setTimeout 10 Seconds. So you can see 10 Seconds the static coded items and after that it will be replaced by JQuery ReplaceWith.

Is there a refresh command or similar ?

Comment: You can see the code in the fiddle of http://www.codeply.com/go/bp/h4udkJOXkr (the "Demo" link target this fiddle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested with your linked code and figured out you have to replaceWith the hole

```
< div class="view">
```

including the carousel-control links. Also I replaced the *#carousel-363119* in your for loop.

That way jquery works like we add a hole new carousel.