# Bootstrap : Slider not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am using [this](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/colourful-tabbed-slider-carousel) tabbed slider. Please visit link to see it in action. this is my CODE

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 4000
  });

  var clickEvent = false;

  $('#myCarousel').on('click', '.nav a', function() {
    clickEvent = true;
    $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  });

  $('#myCarousel').bind('slid', function() {
    // Get currently selected item
    var item = $('#myCarousel .carousel-inner .item.active');

    // Deactivate all nav links
    $('#myCarousel .nav li').removeClass('active');

    // Index is 1-based, use this to activate the nav link based on slide
    var index = item.index() + 1;
    $('#myCarousel .nav li:nth-child(' + index + ')').addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
#myCarousel .nav a small {
  display: block;
}
#myCarousel .nav {
  background: #eee;
}
.nav-justified > li > a {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.nav-pills>li[data-slide-to="0"].active a {
  background-color: #16a085;
}
.nav-pills>li[data-slide-to="1"].active a {
  background-color: #e67e22;
}
.nav-pills>li[data-slide-to="2"].active a {
  background-color: #2980b9;
}
.nav-pills>li[data-slide-to="3"].active a {
  background-color: #8e44ad;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/16a085/ffffff&text=About Us">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Headline</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Item -->
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/e67e22/ffffff&text=Projects">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Headline</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Item -->
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/2980b9/ffffff&text=Portfolio">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Headline</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Item -->
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/8e44ad/ffffff&text=Services">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Headline</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Item -->
    </div>
    <!-- End Carousel Inner -->
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><a href="#">About<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a>
      </li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"><a href="#">Projects<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a>
      </li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"><a href="#">Portfolio<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a>
      </li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"><a href="#">Services<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- End Carousel -->
</div>
```

jQuery files that i've included

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

problem is that along with my slider active tab does not change. `First tab is always active` and top slider keeps on changing. Please if someone can help me with it

Comment: `$('#myCarousel').bind('slid', function () {`  I don't know if this is the problem but does it not need to be `slide` instead of `slid`?

Comment: this is not the issue

Comment: Can you post some html code? And If I understand the question right: the slider is working but the tabs in the bottom are not changing if the slide changes.  If I understand it right I think the following: Your slides are working with a interval of 4 sec but I see nowhere the code to change the tabs.

Comment: @Vinc199789 please check it now complete code

Comment: When is the bind function called? Is it called every 4 sec, everytime a user clicks on a tab? Because if it is called only when the page is loaded I can imagine that the tabs don't change. BTW, open your web console and look if you are getting any errors

Comment: I would say it is the same problem as with my own question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719344/replacewith-carousel-inner-with-new-items

Comment: @Danny so what did you do ?

Comment: @Sikander: I only want to cross link to give additional input for helping users. I assume that we basically have the same problem. You marked the question as answered, but it seems it doesn't work for you - isn't it ? I think it could be a problem from JQuery where the events lost connection to the DOM elements. If you take a look onto my linked example, you will see, after the setTimeout of 10 seconds will froze the slider.

Comment: @Danny Yes you are absolutely right  it didn't work for me but snippet below is working fine so marked it as accepted .. problem is  with jquery/ js  versions at one time it was working fine and i changed some  cdn link now dont know which ones were working and which ones  are not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change event that carousel listens from `slid` to `slid.bs.carousel`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 4000
  });

  var clickEvent = false;

  $('#myCarousel').on('click', '.nav a', function() {
    clickEvent = true;
    $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  });

  $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
    // Get currently selected item
    
    var item = $('#myCarousel .carousel-inner .item.active');

    // Deactivate all nav links
    $('#myCarousel .nav li').removeClass('active');

    // Index is 1-based, use this to activate the nav link based on slide
    var index = item.index() + 1;
    $('#myCarousel .nav li:nth-child(' + index + ')').addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
#myCarousel .nav a small {
  display: block;
}
#myCarousel .nav {
  background: #eee;
}
.nav-justified > li > a {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.nav-pills>li[data-slide-to="0"].active a {
  background-color: #16a085;
}
.nav-pills>li[data-slide-to="1"].active a {
  background-color: #e67e22;
}
.nav-pills>li[data-slide-to="2"].active a {
  background-color: #2980b9;
}
.nav-pills>li[data-slide-to="3"].active a {
  background-color: #8e44ad;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/16a085/ffffff&text=About Us">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Headline</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Item -->
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/e67e22/ffffff&text=Projects">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Headline</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Item -->
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/2980b9/ffffff&text=Portfolio">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Headline</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Item -->
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/8e44ad/ffffff&text=Services">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Headline</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Item -->
    </div>
    <!-- End Carousel Inner -->
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><a href="#">About<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a>
      </li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"><a href="#">Projects<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a>
      </li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"><a href="#">Portfolio<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a>
      </li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"><a href="#">Services<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- End Carousel -->
</div>
```

Comment: What is not working? Click „run code snippet” and please describe what is your expectations

Comment: sorry but i dont know why is it not working for me i pasted same code but still not works , also tried to clear the browser cache but still not able to get result

Comment: @Sikander Is my code example works? Maybe you have problem with connections to internet, maybe your ISP blocks some CDN services?

Comment: let me check  through proxy i also used carousal in other pages so classes used in this example are common to bootstrap carousals  i mean code might not be repeating from cdn's   code